# Disable automatic printer detection in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing

My HP printer has 4 entries under Printers, and I created only one of them. That's the one I want. The multiple entries has to do with USB connected, and network connected, and they get recreated as fast as I can delete them.
How to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `apt purge cups-browsed`? All gone?

Comment: But what will stop them from coming back?

Comment: Keeping cups-browsed uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to try it out. Will I still be able to add a printer manually?

Comment: Indeed you will.