# cups ipp everywhere printer won't delete

Tags: printing

I have a printer that no longer runs with CUPS 2.4.1. In the past, I have been able to delete it from CUPS and then reinstall it to get it working again. Now when I attempt to delete it in CUPS, I get the message "Printer deleted successfully" but the printer will not go away. It is no longer functional from my laptop.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on a Lenovo ThinkPad. The printer works OK from my desktop system running Linux Mint.

The only thing I did differently the last time I configured the printer with CUPS is I tried using the Printer's name (EPSON6055F4) instead of its IP address when configuring IPP Everywhere. I have found a whole bunch of CUPS files on my laptop, but I don't think deleting any of them without knowing what I am doing is a good idea. Anyone have any ideas?

Well I still can't delete this printer from CUPS, but it has mysteriously started working again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345083/how-do-i-disable-automatic-remote-printer-installation)

Comment: Also see [Disable automatic printer detection in Kubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279173/disable-automatic-printer-detection-in-kubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured the answer to my question:
*cups ipp everywhere printer won't delete*

Follow the steps below to remove the configuration file for the printer.

1. cd /etc/cups
2. ls
3. sudo less printers.conf   *(lets you read the printers.conf file)*
4. sudo rm printers.conf     *(lets you remove the printers.conf file)*

This is what I would try if I need to delete a printer that I can't delete from CUPS. This should subsequently allow reconfiguring the printer in CUPS.